# Background Video NOT working on Sharepoint

Tags: html, css, video, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

- I am trying to put a background video on my SharePoint but instead of setting it as a background video it starts playing it and does not work. It works perfectly out of SharePoint (in browser) Need Help Please

Evidently there isn't something fundamentally wrong with my html since it renders in the browser. Are there any sharepoint html5 wizards out there who can help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Oryx Technologies</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">


       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/owl.theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/slicknav.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/responsive.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>





    </head>
    <body>
    <video poster="" id="bgvid"  autoplay muted loop>

<source src="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/Jon%20Hopkins%20-%20Immunity%20(Rowbyte%20Plexus).mp4.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Shared%20Documents/Jon%20Hopkins%20-%20Immunity%20(Rowbyte%20Plexus).mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


        <section class="intro"  id="home">
            <div class="menu-bar menu">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div id="logo">     
                                <a href=""><im src="images/logo.png" alt="" title=""  height="40px" style="float: left;"/></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="main-menu">
                                <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#features">Facebook</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#testimonial">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#screenshots">LinkedIn</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Website</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Menu Ends here -->
            <div class="intro-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 intro-image">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 intro-texts">
                            <h1>Welcome to Oryx Technologies Intranet Portal</h1>
                            <p>Explore Your Posibilities | Run With Oryx</p>

                            <p>Collabrative | Intelligent | Secure</p>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="">Human Resources</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://oryxtech.sharepoint.com/Finance/Pages/default.aspx">Finance</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Sales             </a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Technology        </a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Operations        </a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Marketing         </a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Projects          </a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Investors         </a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Business Partners </a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Technology Partners</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Intro Section Ends -->

        <section class="features" id="features">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 wow fadeIn">
                        <h2>Employee Self Services</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeft">
                        <div class="single-service">
                            <p style="background:#EE3867;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></p>
                            <h3>Submit a Leave Application</h3>

                            <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Click Me</a></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeft">
                        <div class="single-service">
                            <p style="background:#3DB39D;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></p>
                            <h3>Claim an Expense</h3>

                            <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Click Me</a></p>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeInRight">
                        <div class="single-service">
                            <p style="background:#57C7ED;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></p>
                            <h3>Follow a Request</h3>

                            <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Click Me</a></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeInRight">
                        <div class="single-service">
                            <p style="background:#324E5C;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></p>
                            <h3>Submit a Petty Cash Request</h3>
                            <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Click Me</a></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Features Section Ends Here -->
        <section class="app-screenshot">
            <div class="container" id="screenshots">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInUp">
                        <h2>Case Studies</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel col-md-12 wow fadeInUp">
                        <div><img src="images/casesstdtg.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/ateis.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/wadi.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/aggerko.png" alt="" /></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </section>



        <!--Other Features Ends Here-->





        <!-- App Screenshot Ends Here-->


        <!--Testimonial Section Ends Here-->

        <section class="clients-logo" id="clients">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="clients-logo" class="owl-carousel col-md-12 wow slideInRight">
                        <div><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="" /></div>

                        <div><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/skype.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div><img src="images/google-plus.png" alt="" /></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Clients Logo Section Ends Here -->




        <!-- Price List Section Ends Here -->


        <!-- About App Section Ends Here -->


        <!-- Get App Section Ends Here -->


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

              $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
                items : 4,
                navigation : false,
                navigationText : ["prev","next"],
                paginationNumbers: true
              });
               $("#testimonial-carousel").owlCarousel({
                items : 1,
                itemsCustom : true,
                itemsDesktop : [1199,1],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [980,1],
                itemsTablet: [768,1],
                itemsTabletSmall: true,
                itemsMobile : [479,1],
                singleItem : true,
                itemsScaleUp : true,
                responsive : true
               });
               $("#clients-logo").owlCarousel({
                items : 6,
                paginationNumbers : false,
                navigation : false,
               });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          new WOW().init();
        </script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // handle links with @href started with '#' only
            $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
                // target element id
                var id = $(this).attr('href');
                // target element
                var $id = $(id);
                if ($id.length === 0) {
                    return;
                }
                // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
                e.preventDefault();
                // top position relative to the document
                var pos = $(id).offset().top;
                // animated top scrolling
                $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
            $('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').css('background','#000').removeClass('original').hide();
            scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);
            function stickIt() {
              var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
              orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;
              if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
                // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

                // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
                orgElement = $('.original');
                coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
                leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
                widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
                $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
                $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
              } else {
                // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
                $('.cloned').hide();
                $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
              }
            }
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#main-menu').slicknav();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit the relevant HTML into your question? Also, what do you mean by "it starts playing it and does not work"?

Comment: Hi Thiggle, I have added the code. What I meant by it starts playing is, when I embed the code on the SharePoint Site the video starts playing on top of the content and all I see is the video I have tried fixing the z-index but that also couldn't work.